# How to get corresponding label value when i click on it using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

How to get corresponding label value when i click on it for following jsp using javascript

This is my jsp page.

```
<%
for( int i = 0; i < sam.groupName.length; i++ ) {%>
<a href='JavaScript:validation();'>
   <img src='registerButton.jpg'>
   <label for='groupsId' id='labeld"+i+"'><%=sam.groupName[i]%>" </label>
 </a>
<% } %>





<script type="text/javascript">

 function validation(){
   alert("script");
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<a href='#' onclick='validation(this)'>
```

(this will pass the `<a>` element as the first argument to `validation()`)

and then

```
function validation(anchor) {
    alert(anchor.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].textContent);
}
```

Comment: @codeHeart: it will, but will include all the surrounding/formatting whitespace outside the label text.

Comment: I have tried with your code . still couldnot get the label value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578400/how-to-get-corresponding-label-value-when-i-click-on-it-using-javascript/12580961#12580961

Comment: Oh... Looking at your new code, I noticed that you have an extra apostrophe following `labeld` in `id='labeld'" + i + "'`. Remove it, otherwise everything is broken...

Comment: And an error on my side. I overlooked your use of the `href` attribute rather than `onclick`. Instead of `href="javascript:validation(this)"` you should use `href="#" onclick="validation(this)"`. See the fixed answer.